# How to solve system of congruence modulo equations?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, congruences

So I have these two congruence equations, and I need to solve for x and y (or determine that it is unsolvable). I have been searching for hours and can't figure out how to solve this, or how to even find out if it is solvable.

Here are the two equations:

1. *x* + 3 *y* ≡ 3 (*mod 6*)
2. 4 *x* + 3 *y* ≡ 1 (*mod 6*)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see my answer below? If you need more detail to explain it, let me know ...

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract (1) from (2) the system implies $3x \equiv -2 \equiv 4 \ (\mod 6)$ but $3x$ can only be $0$ or $3$ mod $6.$